# JNI code in linux shared lib

Tags: linux, java-native-interface

I have a c++ library ported to linux.
Now I'm adding a JNI code so I can add a java wrapper.
The question is:
Is adding JNI to the same lib will effect the c++ application of the users --> So might it become not working if java not installed ... etc (Because it links to some code in jni.h and other stuff)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't affect the current library if you add JNI to your library. JNI are a collection of interfaces and callback that make your library can be used by JVM. Without JNI, your library can't be used from JVM.

Your library will grow up in size and more symbols be exported when you add JNI.

By adding JNI to your current library, it means your library can be used as a normal library meanwhile can be loaded from JVM.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider creating a JNI wrapper in C/C++ and statically link to your current library.  That way your currently library will still work for C/C++ apps and your code will be easier to debug and maintain.  If you choose this route, you may also want to look into enabling link-time optimization for your JNI wrapper.  Alternatively you could also dynamically link the JNI wrapper and just put both libraries in /lib (or where ever is appropriate), but you will have a runtime dependency on that base library.